# Adding IF statement to a featureLayer in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to filter what features get plotted to the map based on the users email that logs in to the site. So far, I've tried multiple options and keep getting stumped. Here's the code I have currently. Please help.

Here's the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_leaflet_id' of undefined at Object.stamp (leaflet.js:6) at e.addLayer (leaflet.js:6) at e._addLayers (leaflet.js:6) at e.initialize (leaflet.js:6) at new e (leaflet.js:6) at Object.o.map (leaflet.js:6) at app.js:810

```
var userEmail = $("#email").val();

    if (userEmail.includes("fibertel")) {
      var featureLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
        filter: function(feature, layer) {
          if (feature.properties.contractor === "FiberTel") return true;
        },
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
          return L.marker(latlng, {
            title: feature.properties["status_title_github"],
            riseOnHover: true,
            icon: L.icon({
              iconUrl: "assets/pictures/markers/cb0d0c.png",
              iconSize: [30, 40],
              iconAnchor: [15, 32]
            })
          });
        },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
          if (feature.properties) {
            layer.on({
              click: function (e) {
                identifyFeature(L.stamp(layer));
                highlightLayer.clearLayers();
                highlightLayer.addData(featureLayer.getLayer(L.stamp(layer)).toGeoJSON());
              },
              mouseover: function (e) {
                if (config.hoverProperty) {
                  $(".info-control").html(feature.properties[config.hoverProperty]);
                  $(".info-control").show();
                }
              },
              mouseout: function (e) {
                $(".info-control").hide();
              }
            });
            if (feature.properties["marker-color"]) {
              layer.setIcon(
                L.icon({
                  iconUrl: "assets/pictures/markers/" + feature.properties["marker-color"].replace("#",'').toLowerCase() + ".png",
                  iconSize: [30, 40],
                  iconAnchor: [15, 32]
                })
              );
            }
          }
        }
      });
    } else if
```

Comment: While not optimized, your `if` / `else if` looks to be doing what you are trying to achieve. Then you need to `addData` to your `featureLayer` (which is actually a Leaflet GeoJSON Layer Group). If you need help, please explain what does not work, share potential error messages, add sample data and the associated code.

Comment: What do you mean by not optimized? You mean using a function()? I could but, then all the other coding that refers to the featureLayer would have to be fixed and I don't want to worry about that right now. I want to see it work first.

Comment: Here's the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_leaflet_id' of undefined
    at Object.stamp (leaflet.js:6)
    at e.addLayer (leaflet.js:6)
    at e._addLayers (leaflet.js:6)
    at e.initialize (leaflet.js:6)
    at new e (leaflet.js:6)
    at Object.o.map (leaflet.js:6)
    at app.js:810

Comment: I have the addData code else where

Comment: You should _edit_ your question to include the error stack trace. It explains much better your issue, so it is important for people to be able to help you solve it.

Comment: "_While not optimized…_" indeed I am not saying you should optimize it right now, first make it work! :-)

Comment: I guess the error happens when you click, not when you first display your layers? Please add this detail in your question as well, it is also important to understand your situation.

Comment: When does the filtering happen? Once when loading the page, every time the user edits a `<input>`, or something else?

Comment: So I did some troubleshooting last night and came to the conclusion that the issue is happening at the var userEmail part. If I change that to the word I’m filtering against it works just fine. It’s as if the map is adding the featureLayer before the var userEmail is returning the email from the sign in (which is what the var in the question above is referring to). Any thoughts on how to return the email first then add the featureLayer to the map? I would much rather use var userEmail= sessionStorage.getItem, but that didn’t work either.